# Incriminating others vs. Incriminating the others: Is this sentence correct?

Tags: definite-articles, syntactic-analysis

From [Oxford dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/incriminate) :

> He was careful not to say anything that might incriminate the others.

Should it not be "He was careful not to say anything that might **incriminate others**"? If the sentence in the dictionary is correct, what does "the" signify here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a non-native speaker, you perhaps need to make yourself more familiar with the use of the English definite and indefinite articles. Briefly, the significance of *the* in the sentence is that it limits *others* to those that have already been mentioned earlier in the conversation or narrative.

Comment: In this case it is a single line and "others" have not been mentioned earlier . So I do not understand why you are assuming that there have been references to "others" in the past .

Comment: @Geek, exactly because the definite article is there.

Comment: @Geek: The single line is an extract. As the previous comment says, the presence of the definite article forces us to assume an earlier mention.

Comment: ...in essence, with an excerpt we must assume either the article refers to an earlier (not included) phrase, or it's a mistake. Since there are no premises to assume the latter, the correct course of action is to assume the former.

Comment: @SF: especially when the context is an example sentence in a dictionary!

Answer (score 2):

To me, it suggests that the speaker is a member of some group, and the article *the* implies that he didn't say anything to incriminate those in the rest of the group.

Omitting the article would make the sentence mean he was careful not to incriminate *anyone*.  But when you say *the others*, it refers to some subset of people.

What group?  It could be a gang of theives, a corporate board, members of a political party, members of his family, cosuspects in a case, codefendents in a lawsuit.  The sentence only provides a pronoun – so, nobody knows what group it is!  However, I'm confident that, with more information (who was talking, the nature of the questioning, etc.), I could figure it out.

For example, if the person was Lance Armstrong, and the sentence was uttered this week, I would surmise that *the others* might refer to fellow cyclists, probably on his team.